# Reading two excel row simultaneously in java

Tags: java

I have property file with column name and values. How to read the file with two rows simultaneously and add Key Value pair in the has-map.
Also if any Key Name get's no mapping then that should be omitted from the map.

[image: column names and values]

```
    public class ExcelReader {
    public static ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> cmMappingHashMap = new 
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    public static String str;
    public static Row row;
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\test\\Downloads\\contacts.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = firstSheet.rowIterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Row row2 = rowIterator.next();
                row2.setRowNum(1);
                System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
                // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator1 = row2.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()&&cellIterator1.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    Cell cell1 = cellIterator1.next();
                    System.out.println(cell.getColumnIndex());
                      System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "--"+cell1.getNumericCellValue());
                }
            }
    }
}
```

With the above code getting exception in thread "main" `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

I wanted to add the First Row's Cell 1 to second rows cell 1 like wise follows

```
 Key ----Value
 Name----1
 ID------2
 Name----3
```

---

I have created following code to achieve above based on various inputs present on the stack.

```
 public void readPosition() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
 columnNameArray = new String[propertyFilecolumnCount];
 Workbook wb = null;
 wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new 
 File("C:\\Users\\aaa\\Downloads\\Mapping_Data_Upload.xlsx")));
 Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
 Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext()){
  Row row = itr.next();
  Iterator<Cell> cellItrator = row.iterator();
    if(row.getRowNum()==0){
      while(cellItrator.hasNext()){
        Cell  cell = cellItrator.next();
        String cellString =cell.toString();
          if(cellString.length()!=0){
            columnNameArray[cell.getColumnIndex()]=cellString;
           }
       }
     }
    if(row.getRowNum()==1){
    columnValueArray=new String[columnNameArray.length];
    int columnIndex=0;
    List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    int lastColumn = Math.max(row.getLastCellNum(), 7);
     for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
         Cell c = row.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
          if(c==null){
            cellValue="Null";
            columnIndex =columnIndex+1;
            columnValueArray[columnIndex]=cellValue;
        }
        else{
         cells.add(c);
         columnValueArray[c.getColumnIndex()]=c.toString();
                                columnIndex=c.getColumnIndex();
        }
       }
    for (int j=0,int k=0;j<columnNameArray.length && k<columnValueArray.length;j++,k++){
      if(columnValueArray[k].equalsIgnoreCase("Null")){
       }
      else{
           double val=Double.parseDouble(columnValueArray[k]);
          int value=(int) Math.round(val);
          MappingHashMap.put(columnNameArray[j], value);
            }
        }
        columnNameArray=null;
        columnValueArray=null;
        }
```

Because for some columns I am not getting mapping because that is not present in the data file. So I have to remove that columnName from the has map.

```
ID | FName | LName | Address| City| Zip| Degree| Stdt| EndDt| 
1  | 2     |  3    |4       | 5    |    |      |  6 |   7   |
```

This way I am getting out put as follows by using above code.  Is there any effective way to get the following

```
Key ----Value
ID---1
FName----2
LName----3
Address---4
City------4
Stdt----5
enddt----6
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Afraid this is way too broad at present, can you show a [mcve] of what you have so far?

Comment: I have provided the current code that i am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading the two lines directly, you can create a model class with attributes Name, ID and then you can instantiate the object and assign the values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem line is, I have a data mapping sheet and the column numbers are the position in the data file. Each time there will be different mapping as per client's need. To run few rules based on the provided mapping I wanted to create  LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>.  like wise
Key -- Value
ID --->1
Name-->3
FullName-->3
First Name--> 4